# not found: type Registration?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I followed this tutorial: http://yobriefca.se/blog/2012/05/08/starter-for-10-scala/
and after running the app, I got this:

[image]

I'm sure that te code in the tutorial an the app is exactly the same.

I'm using `Play 2.0.4`. The tutorial uses `Play 2.0.1`. Not sure if that's the reason or its because the version of a dependency?

**Tutorial:**

Scala (2.9.1)

Mongo (2.0.4)

**Me:**

Scala (2.9.2)

Mongo (2.2.1)

Comment: Did you put `Registration` model in `models` package ? can you publish the code somewhere (ie. github?)

Comment: Try using the fully qualified path of `Registration`.

Comment: @biesior hey you are right. I had to do `package models` and `import models` (as well as importing other things). I guess I'm too used to Rails so these things are pretty new. Could you post an answer so I can check it?)

Comment: @biesior Now I can see the form but when I submit. Nothing happens. I can see a 404 Bad Request flshing int he Chrome inspector for some milliseconds (no error messages whatsoever). The code is exactly the same as in the repo: https://github.com/kouphax/scala-sampleapp I double checked it twice. God, it's so hard to make this thing work.

Comment: You can switch an option in Chrome's inspector which will keep all mesaages between requests, so you'll be able to check the source of the error. Sorry I don't know that sample and currently tapping from the pad.